# Apache OpenNLP python wrapper - server timeout

Tags: apache, server, opennlp

Hi I am trying to use Apache OpenNLP with the Python wrapper but now when I try to start the server it just times out and I can't find where I might be supposed to extend the timeout from. Do I need anything else installed relating to Apache to be able to run the server?

```
python opennlp/opennlp.py --path /home/sandra/apache-opennlp-1.8.4
Starting OpenNLP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opennlp/opennlp.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "opennlp/opennlp.py", line 60, in main
    nlp = OpenNLP(options.path)
  File "opennlp/opennlp.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.process.expect('done')
  File "/home/sandra/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 321, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async)
  File "/home/sandra/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 345, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/home/sandra/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 107, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "/home/sandra/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 70, in timeout
    raise TIMEOUT(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x7f3ff84d5d50>
command: /home/sandra/apache-opennlp-1.8.4/bin/opennlp
args: ['/home/sandra/apache-opennlp-1.8.4/bin/opennlp', 'Parser', '/home/sandra/apache-opennlp-1.8.4/models/en-parser-chunking.bin']
buffer (last 100 chars): ''
before (last 100 chars): ''
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 18013
child_fd: 6
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your path of apache open nlp. Where have you installed it? maybe a part of your code you have to write on your question. I had the same problem and it was because of path of apache open nlp.

token = opennlp.OpenNLP("opennlp-python/apache-opennlp-1.8.4", "TokenNameFinder", "sq-ner-location.bin")
            persed = token.parse(data)
            print(persed)

check this out [opennlp](https://github.com/curzona/opennlp-python)